# Disable cache for specific admin page

Tags: caching

Is it possible to disable the cache on specific admin pages ?
I'm trying to hide some menu in "admin/structure/menu" but because it's for different roles, the cache has to be flushed to make it work.

Any idea ?

Cheers

Comment: I was doing this code : https://drupal.org/node/1218666 and before that I was checking the $user->roles if their was administrator among and display the new list of menu.

Comment: before that?  you should be doing the check of the `$user->roles` INSIDE the callback...

Comment: Ah it seems that was the trick ! Thank you Jimajamma